# blackberry tableview solution for jde 4.5

Tags: tableview, blackberry-jde, listfield

I am very new to blackberry table view. I am using jde 4.5. Can anyone please which is best way  to show

by this forum :  **http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/10/how-to-use-table-view-layout/**

or **Customize ListField**

I want a structure like below

Text

Text               |  ButtonField

Text               |  ButtonField

Text

**---------------------------------**

Text

Text               |  ButtonField

Text               |  ButtonField

Text

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new TableModel class in OS 6. There is sample code and explanation on how to do it in blackberry docs. check out this link  - http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29204/Table_Model_1328111_11.jsp